# how to find related field month by in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my table schema

### Month      BD Name   Payment Amount      Total Paid      Due Amount

```
July,2017   Mohit Siwal       70                 210      -140
August,2017 Mohit Siwal       350                150      200
September 2017  Mohit Siwal    277               556        -279
September 2017  Mohit Siwal     500                 250    250
September 2017  Mohit Siwal   250               500         -250
November 2017   Mohit Siwal     200              100    100
```

i want to add all September month and add also related field in this table;

come like this **output**

```
Month        BD Name    Payment Amount        Total Paid    Due Amount
July 2017   Mohit Siwal      70                      210    -140
August 2017 Mohit Siwal      350                     150    200
September 2017  Mohit Siwal   1027                 1306     -279
November 2017   Mohit Siwal    200                    100   100
```

I am written this query

```
$countryquery="select id, project_name, SUM(total_paid) as t, bd_id, payment_date from `tbl_payments`where bd_id=$bid Group By project_name order by payment_date" ;
```

Comment: Always store dates as dates

Comment: the query you show seems not the related  to the schema  ...  the column name don't match  ..

Answer (score 0):

You can group by month and bd_name and find sum of the amounts:

```
select month,
    bd_name,
    sum(payment_amount) as payment_amount,
    sum(total_paid) as total_paid,
    sum(due_amount) as due_amount
from your_table
group by month,
    bd_name
order by month;
```